# How to solve `fsck:error 2(No such file or directory)` while executing `fsck.ext2` for `/dev/nvme0n1p2`?

Tags: boot, server, filesystem, fsck

I’m facing this error while executing `fsck.ext2` for `/dev/nvme0n1p2`:

```
fsck:error 2 (No such file or directory)
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. One cannot `fsck` a partition if it's mounted; One must be `root` to `fsck`.